# Hitting validation api and saving user session after login

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication

So currently, the user types in a username and password in a typical form. On submit, the login method is called and user credentials are checked against backend api. If valid, then store the username in localStorage and check if user is logged in throughout the application via route guard (that is, if name is stored in localStorage, they are logged in and can navigate safely throughout the app).

While this is currently working, there might be some gotchas with what if user goes back to /login page route, they have to log in again instead of returning user back to homepage or real back.

And there might be other scenarios I'm not thinking of right now and I'm wondering, what's best practice? How can improve this code? What are the possible security holes or holes in general with this code?

Here's my login method:

```
login(credentials: User, isValid: boolean) {
        this.userId = credentials.userId;
        this.password = credentials.password;

        this.userService.validateUser(credentials.userId, credentials.password).subscribe(data => {
          this.userloginInfo = data;

         if (localStorage.getItem('username')) {

          localStorage.removeItem('username');
          localStorage.setItem('username', credentials.userId.toUpperCase());

       } else {
        localStorage.setItem('username', credentials.userId.toUpperCase());
       }

          this.displayErrors = false;
          console.log('login success');
          this.authService.login(credentials.userId.toUpperCase());
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);

      }, (err) => {
            this.displayErrors = true;
            console.log('login failed');
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same route guard but add some logic.

Every time you go to the login page it should check if the user is already logged in. I do that by setting a login flag, stored in a service, to true every time a request using your credentials, or access token, is successful/valid.

So, the only way you should be able to make it back to the login page is if the login local storage, or login flag, you create is cleared or false.